# Unable to load resource for composite template

Tags: gtk3, vala

I have a very basic GTK application written in Vala (non-working source tree [here](https://gitlab.com/gergelypolonkai/gauthenticator/tree/ffc118c47cb24a1dffeb6e5482e90bf9ed9f38a2)), which intend to load the resources for the main application window from a GResource.

So I created a resource file, compiled it with `glib-compile-resources` and also added it to `VALAFLAGS` as `--gresources=$(top_srcdir)/data/gauthenticator.gresource.xml`.

The relevant part of the data file looks like this:

```
<gresource prefix="/eu/polonkai/gergely/gauthenticator">
    <file preprocess="xml-stripblanks">gauth-window.ui</file>
</gresource>
```

and I use it like this:

```
[GtkTemplate (ui = "/eu/polonkai/gergely/gauthenticator/gauth-window.ui")]
class Window : Gtk.ApplicationWindow {
    [GtkChild]
    private Gtk.ProgressBar countdown;
}
```

The relevant part of my `Makefile.am`:

```
gresource_file = $(top_srcdir)/data/gauthenticator.gresource.xml
gauthenticator_VALAFLAGS = --pkg gtk+-3.0 --target-glib=2.38 --gresources $(gresource_file)
```

All is well during compilation, but in runtime I get this error:

```
(gauthenticator:16501): Gtk-CRITICAL **: Unable to load resource for composite template for type 'GAuthenticatorWindow': The resource at '/eu/polonkai/gergely/gauthenticator/gauth-window.ui' does not exist

(gauthenticator:16501): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_class_bind_template_child_full: assertion 'widget_class->priv->template != NULL' failed

(gauthenticator:16501): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_init_template: assertion 'template != NULL' failed
```

I copied most resource-related lines from the GNOME Boxes repository, but obviously missed something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you compiling the resources with `glib-compile-resources`? I would recommend compiling it to a C file:

`glib-compile-resources --sourcedir data --generate-source --target my_build_dir/resources/resources.c data/gauthenticator.gresource.xml`

Then add `my_build_dir/resources/resources.c` to your `_SOURCES` so it gets compiled along with your Vala sources. The `--gresources` option for `valac` only does type checking for Vala's GTK+ composite template support.

I've not tried compiling a GResource C file as part of a Vala to C and then C to binary compilation process. At the moment it looks like you are just using `valac` for the whole compilation process.